# SAS- How to count the type in one column

Tags: sas

Assuming a dataset as shown following.

```
dossier_manager 
NameA   
NameA   
NameB   
NameC   
NameC   
NameC   
NameD   
NameD   
NameE   
NameF
```

I want to know how many different names are in there. I tried `proc freq` but I have too many different names in the column that make the frequency list significant long. So how could I get a sample result? Like 6 (different names) in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `proc sql`, use `count(distinct(dossier_manager))`

If you need a sample, you can `select distinct` values of `dossier_manager` and limit the number of rows in the output using `outobs=`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the distinct names as well as unique count also.

```
proc sql;
select distinct dossier_manager ,count(distinct dossier_manager)
from test;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Neal,

One common technique is too report on only the top N most frequent values and a summary of the remaining.  Consider this sample code:

```
* fake data, 10,000 rows of a normally distributed variable. (ranuni would be quite flat);
data have;
  do row = 1 to 10000;
    my_char_var = cats('x',ceil (10 + 10*rannor(1234)));
    my_num_var = ceil (10 + 10*rannor(1234));
    output;
  end;
run;

* compute the raw frequency counts;
proc freq data=have noprint order=freq ;
  table my_num_var / out=counts ;
run;

* specify parameters for desired TOP N;
%let topN = 10;
%let REMAIN_N = 0;

* dow loop over all data, outputting top N freqs and accumulating the remainder;
data want(keep=my_num_var count percent); 
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 while (not end_flag);

    set counts end=end_flag;

    if _n_ > &topN then do;
      accumN + 1;
      accumCNT + count;
      accumPCT + percent;
    end;
    else OUTPUT;
  end;

  * output remainder counts if there are any - special missing value .R used to indicate REMAINDER bin;
  if accumN ne . then do;
    my_num_var = .R;
    * my_char_var = "*REMAIN*";
    count = accumCNT;
    percent = accumPCT; 
    output;
    call symputx ('REMAIN_N', accumN);
  end;

  stop;
run;

* create a custom format that will indicate how many distinct other values are not top N;
proc format; value REMAINING .R="Remaining (&REMAIN_N.)";
proc format; value $REMAINING "*REMAIN*"="Remaining (&REMAIN_N.)";

* apply custom format in PRINT procedure, this will override the format of the tabled variable;
proc print data=want;
  format my_num_var REMAINING.;
run;
```

Output

```
Obs      my_num_var      COUNT    PERCENT

  1                 9      398      3.98
  2                11      394      3.94
  3                 6      388      3.88
  4                 8      383      3.83
  5                 7      378      3.78
  6                10      374      3.74
  7                13      374      3.74
  8                14      366      3.66
  9                12      353      3.53
 10                17      350      3.50
 11    Remaining (64)     6242     62.42
```

Minor tweaks needed for doing same with a character variable.

Small logic changes could give you top N with individual % > threshold, top N with cumulative % < threshold, top N with individual count > threshold or top N with cumulative < threshold.

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont want to use Proc SQL:

If you just want to get total number of ITEMS then do as

-- Apply  the Proc Freq for the data and put that into a SAS data D1
    (using OUT statement).

-- Then apply Proc contents data on this data (D1) to extract number of observations through another OUT STATEMENT.

Let me know in case you want the code for this.